# Building an R package in Windows

Tags: r, windows-10, rcpp

I am trying to build an R package in Windows using Rtools v3.4 (latest)

I have developed a package with Rcpp and I have built it in an Ubuntu system successfully, but when I try to build it in my Windows 10 machine with the command

```
R CMD INSTALL --build --compile-both mypackage
```

I got the following error:

```
file1.hpp:25:18:   required from here
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:110:30: error: invalid conversion from 'const void*' to 'void*' [-fpermissive]
   { ::operator delete(__p); }
```

My Makefile.win file has this lines:

```
PKG_CPPFLAGS=-I./dep1/src -I./dep2/cudd -I./dep2/mtr -I./dep2/cplusplus -I./dep2/dddmp -I./dep2/util -I./dep2
CXX_STD=CXX11
PKG_LIBS=-llib1 -lm -fPIC -L./include/windows -llib2
```

What could be the reasson of that error?

**Edit after @DirkEddelbuettel comment:**

If add the -fpermissive flag I solve that issue, but a new error appears

```
R CMD INSTALL --build --compile-both -fpermissive mypackage

file1.hpp:95:71:   required from here
C:/Rtools/mingw_32/i686-w64-mingw32/include/c++/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: invalid static_cast from type 'const std::basic_string<char>*' to type 'void*'
 { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
```

The conflicting class has the following structure:

```
#ifndef __myKconf__configInfo__
#define __myKconf__configInfo__

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class myClass : public parentClass {
    public :
        myClass() {
            ...
        }

    //some public methods

    void addToMenu(const std::string& s) {
        contents.push_back(s);
    }

    private:
        std::vector<const std::string> contents;
        //more private elements
};
#endif
```

Comment: Try adding `-fpermissive`. Nobody can tell what is wrong with code *you did not post*.  See 'minimally reproducible example' for more.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel it works, but a new error appears now. I have edit the question

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel you are right, without a code example it is difficut. I have added the conflicting line, I hope that helps

Comment: Repeat after me: "minimally reproducible example".  A line of code does not cut it.  Your code, your problem.  You have both systems, so truncate it down.

Comment: Problem was a simple typographical error of using a `const std::string` instead of a `std::string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to add to a constant string...

```
private:
    std::vector<const std::string> contents;
    //more private elements
```

Make it:

```
private:
    std::vector<std::string> contents;
```

And you should be golden

Comment: Still not working... And why the same code compiles fine in Ubuntu? Could be related with the mingw's c++ libraries?

Comment: What I can tell you is based on the code snippet and a `'const std::basic_string<char>*' to type 'void*'` you most likely are trying to work with a constant object somewhere and that constant object will kick and scream to avoid having it be touched. For anything more, we will need to see the code in a **minimally reproducible example**.